# Deployment in Azure not working correctly

Tags: .net, azure-devops, deployment, azure-pipelines-yaml, .net-4.7.2

I am currently working on an interface based on a .NET 4.7 framework. The data is pushed to Azure via Sourcetree and then deployed accordingly. This is the code of my YAML file of the pipeline:

```
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2022'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  targetDirectory: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\projectName'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=false /p:PackageLocation="$(targetDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish artifacts'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(targetDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'PublishBuildArtifacts'
    preservePaths: false
```

Unfortunately, the deployments are always "staggered". Thus, the current version is never visible on the website. It only shows the output of 2 to 3 previous deployments. However, the artifacts on Azure and the data on the FTP server are up to date.

Has anyone had to deal with a similar problem and could help me?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you please help clarify what you mean by "the deployments are always "staggered"? In your yaml file, I only see the steps of building your project without any deployment. Could you please share the yaml file you use for deployment? It's better to share the error message if there is.

Comment: The page does not show the customizations of the current release. Only after some deployments later, the page shows the data of an older deployment. Unfortunately I don't have a YAML file of the release. I use the FTP upload in Azure for this.

Comment: Based on my understanding, you use DevOps pipeline to build your project and publish the artifact.  Then you use [FTP Upload task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/ftp-upload?view=tfs-2017&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops) to upload the artifact to a remote machine. Is this correct? If so, the FTP Upload task is only used to upload files. How do you deploy it later? What service are you deploying? The service you are deploying is on your local mahcine or somewhere else? For example, Azure web app, etc.

Comment: I have now created a build before deployment, whereupon the data compiled and the dll files were created correctly. But now there is the problem that CS and CSHTML files are also published (which of course should not happen for privacy reasons).

Comment: Do you mean that CS and CSHTML files were published into the artifact? If you don't want these files to be published into artifact, you can put these files in a directory other than the "PathtoPublish" you specify in "PublishBuildArtifacts". If my understanding is wrong, please help correct me.

Comment: No, you're right. I am currently trying to define this in my YAML file.

Comment: You can use [CopyFiles task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/copy-files-v2?view=azure-pipelines&tabs=yaml) to copy your target files (The files you want to publish into the artifact) to a new folder. Then set this new folder as the value of "PathtoPublish" of "PublishBuildArtifacts task.